# How to vanish session completely in Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I have two JSP pages: Login and Index
and three Servlets: LoginServlet, LogoutServlet, Profile
. Now I want to see my profile only when session has something in it. In LoginServlet's post() I wrote the logic for setting in attribute, and in LogoutServlet's get() I called invalidate() method to remove session. Now When I go to profile url directly without calling Login page, if block of Profile.class gets executed instead of else with nothing in session.getAttribute("name").

Get method of Profile:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    req.getRequestDispatcher("link.jsp").include(req, resp);  
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
    if (session != null) {
        System.out.println("Session is not null");
        out.print("Hello " + session.getAttribute("name"));
    } else {
        out.print("Please login");
        req.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp").include(req, resp);
    }
    out.close();
}
```

Is there something I need to do extra to completely vanish session.

Comment: why you call req.getRequestDispatcher("link.jsp").include(req, resp) ?

Comment: Your posted code should work. Before you browsed to Profile, did you close your browser?  If not, then the session cookie was still held.

Comment: @rickz Yes, I used different browsers to be sure that cookie is not the cause of it. I changed the if condition: if(session.getAttribute("name")!=null) and it's working how I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

In Login class use something like:

```
if (isValidUser(userName, userPass)) {
    request.getSession(true);
    request.getSession.setAttribute("isLogged", true);
}
```

In LogoutServlet class use this code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, ....

    request.getSession().invalidate(); // Vanish session completely
    ....
```

In Profile class to validate that user is logged, use something like:

```
if ((Boolean) request.getSession.getAttribute("isLogged") != null) {
    ... // user is logged
} else
    redirectToIndexPage();
```

Comment: I completely got your point. You want me to provide req.getSession().getAttribute("name") as condition in if block. But, since I am using getSession(false) method which should not create a new instance, if it is not there already. I want to know the possible cause for session object not being null.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation of **HttpServletRequest**

> **getSession()** --
>                 Returns the current HttpSession associated with this request or, if there is no current session and create is true, returns a new session.

Whether session present or not,the request.getSession() is always going to give you an instance of Session.Thats why your if condition will always be true.So basically you need to change your if and else condition.Instead of checking for session,you should check for something else like

```
if(session.getAttribute("name")!=null)
//perform something
```

### See Also

- [Documentation of HTTPServletRequest](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)

I tried creating a servlet and testing what you specified.I am redirecting directly to this servlet.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

        if (session != null) {
            System.out.println("Session is not null");  
        } else {
            System.out.println("Session is null");
        }

    }
```

Output

```
Session is null
```

Comment: True, getSession() will always return an instance, if not present then it creates a new instance and returns it. But,I somewhere read that getSession(false) will return instance only if it is already there and will never create a new instance.

Comment: I tried creating a servlet and checking sesssion as u specified.it works for me.editing my answer.